# Get a Dictionary Value Using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dictionary

I am trying to access an object stored in a dictionary of type String, UnknownClass. I have the key, and know the value is one of several container classes. Since the value is passed to a method that takes an object, I do not need to know the type of the class stored as a value. I also need to call ContainsKey to confirm the key exists.

I have tried the following methods with no success:

```
Dictionary<String, object> list = (Dictionary<String, object>)source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName).GetValue(source, null);
nextSource = list[key];
```

Which gives me a casting error, and:

```
nextSource = source.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item").Invoke(source, new object[] { key });
```

Which gives me a null reference exception.

Here is a bit more of the code, although I am not quite sure it will help much.

```
private void SetValue(object source, String path, String value)
{
    if (path.Contains('.'))
    {
        //  If this is not the ending Property, continue recursing
        int index = path.IndexOf('.');
        String property = path.Substring(0, index);

        object nextSource;
        if(property.Contains("*"))
        {
            path = path.Substring(index + 1);
            index = path.IndexOf('.');
            String dictionaryName = path.Substring(0, index);

            Dictionary<String, object> list = (Dictionary<String, object>)source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName).GetValue(source, null);
            nextSource = list[property.Substring(1)];
            //property = property.Substring(1);
            //nextSource = source.GetType().GetMethod("Item").Invoke(source, new[] { property });
        } ...
```

The dictionary being accessed is defined in the PersonObject class as such:

```
public class PersonObject
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public AddressObject Address { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, HobbyObject> Hobbies { get; set; }
```

The value of Path, at this stage, is set to `"*Hiking.Hobbies.Hobby"`. Basically, the path string allows me to navigate to a Property in a subclass, and I need the Dictionary to access properties for a list of the same class.

Comment: Have you validated that `source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName).GetValue(source, null)` is returning the reference to the dictionary or is it returning `null`? EDIT: if it is returning the dictionary properly, maybe just use `dynamic` instead: `dynamic list = (dynamic)source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName).GetValue(source, null); nextSource = (object)list[key];`

Comment: am damn sure source is null if not this should work

Comment: Source is not null. When I call this, I get an InvalidCastException. The actual dictionary that I am accessing for this specific example is of type <String, Person>.

Comment: can you post ur original code, which will help to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Maybe you can just do something like `object nextSource = ((dynamic)source)[key]`. When you use the `dynamic` type, things will compile with no questions, but the _binding_, in this case binding of the indexer `[key]`, will not happen until runtime where it is known what members the actual runtime type possesses.

Comment: The source points to the class that the Dictionary resides in. I need to get the dictionary using reflection, and this is where I am getting the exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) implements the non-generic [IDictionary Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx). So if you have a variable of tye `object` containing the reference to a `Dictionary<String, HobbyObject>` instance, you can retrieve values in the dictionary as follows:

```
object obj = new Dictionary<String, HobbyObject>
{
    { "Hobby", new HobbyObject() }
};

IDictionary dict = obj as IDictionary;
if (dict != null)
{
    object value = dict["Hobby"];
    // value is a HobbyObject
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to do this:

```
var source = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var key = "some key";
source.Add(key, "some value");

var property = source.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
var value = property.GetValue(source, new[] { key });

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString()); // some value
```

---

**Update:** The problem is that a `Dictionary<string, HobbyObject>` cannot be cast to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. I think you'd have to do this:

```
private void SetValue(object source, String path, String value)
{
    if (path.Contains('.'))
    {
        //  If this is not the ending Property, continue recursing
        int index = path.IndexOf('.');
        String property = path.Substring(0, index);

        object nextSource;
        if(property[0] = '*')
        {
            path = path.Substring(index + 1);
            index = path.IndexOf('.');
            String dictionaryName = path.Substring(0, index);

            property = property.Substring(1);

            Object list = source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName)
                                .GetValue(source, null);
            nextSource = list.GetType().GetProperty("Item")
                             .GetValue(list, new[] { property });
        }
```

Comment: I modified the code to this: nextSource = source.GetType().GetMethod("Item").Invoke(source, new[] { property }); Unfortunately, I am still getting a null reference exception. I have checked, and both "source" and "property" are checked.

Comment: @Tim Perhaps I misunderstood your issue; it's hard to see where your problem might be. Please post more code so I can see the full context.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified the question with additional code, although I'm not sure how much it will actually help.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, that does clear things up a bit. See my updated answer.